# NodeJS или Comet

Tags: node.js, comet

Есть выделенный сервер. Управление удалённое.

Первый вопрос будет про NodeJS. Чтобы его установить, нужно ввести какую-то команду в консоль. Но где эта консоль находится? Как в неё попасть?

Может есть что-то проще? Слышал про comet, но толковой инструкции не нашёл.

Помогите, пожалуйста с NodeJS и желательно подробные инструкции. С comet тоже бы хотел разобраться...

Comment: Все ответы есть в гугле. Да и здесь тоже.

Comment: А Вы случаем не знакомы с хелпер.юкоз.ry?

Comment: @exec, был там давно. А ты вроде uWeb или как там... ) Насчёт гугла, я искал ночами, но ничего умного не нашёл :(

Comment: @ModaL, ух, лихие 2008..

Comment: @exec, дааа. Я ещё помню твой сайт с фотографиями городов ;) highfeed тоже очень понравился!

Comment: @ModaL, первый опыт. С ужасом вспоминаю время разработки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [подключение к консоли сервера](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+nodejs&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=opera&hs=7Ml&tbo=d&rls=ru&channel=suggest&spell=1&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0&sa=X&ei=Zbn9UOLBH8704QSh-YGABw&ved=0CC0QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE&fp=648ecc987964be0a&biw=1680&bih=862)
- - [установка и настройка node js](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+nodejs&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=opera&hs=6Ll&tbo=d&rls=ru&channel=suggest&spell=1&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+node+js&sa=X&ei=Jrn9ULiBN-mB4gTw-IH4Dg&ved=0CDAQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE&fp=648ecc987964be0a&biw=1680&bih=862)
- - - [comet приложение](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+nodejs&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=opera&hs=0Nl&tbo=d&rls=ru&channel=suggest&spell=1&q=comet+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&sa=X&ei=nLn9ULGKJcaI4gTfpYBA&ved=0CC0QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE&fp=648ecc987964be0a&biw=1680&bih=862)
- - - - [comet socket.io пример](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+nodejs&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=opera&hs=yjQ&tbo=d&rls=ru&channel=suggest&q=comet+socket.io+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80&sa=X&ei=67n9UJmlNaSR4AT2xYG4DQ&ved=0CC0Q7xYoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE&fp=648ecc987964be0a&biw=1680&bih=862)

Comment: @exec, спасибо тебе. Сейчас буду вникать :)

Answer (score 4):

Честно говоря- NodeJS и Comet это технологии друг с другом связанные довольно слабо (ровно так же, как php связан с javascript).
**NodeJS** - это серверное приложение, которое дает возможность написать сервер на JavaScript.
**Comet**- это клиентская часть, которая реализует длинные запросы через аякс.
Сравнивать эти две технологии неправильно.

Comment: @ReinRaus Верно подмечено. Добавлю, что Comet покрывает все методы, кроме WebSocket, т.к. последняя, "хаком" не считается - читай полноценный протокол.

NodeJS и PhpDaemon относятся к реализации неблокирующей серверная части - весящий демон, который создаёт процессы, а Comet и WebSocket "интерфейсы" взаимодействия на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернатива Node-ам, посмотрите в сторону [PhpDaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) г-на Зорина или [dklab_realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/) г-на Котерова.

Первый, имеет множество плюшек, в том числе, умеет работать с WebSocket-ом. Последний же, построен на Long Polling.

Comment: @romeo, то, что Вы предложили, довольно трудно для меня. Я не такой спец в установках по таким вещам. Отметил Мне нравится на Вашем ответе, так как вроде бы всё ясно и с одной стороны не ясно :D

Comment: @ModaL С точки зрения простоты, то Node.js проще запустить из коробки, т.к. имеется множество примеров под тот же socket.io.

Решение Котерова тоже в подробностях описано, но метод Long Polling, это вчерашний день. 

Что касается PhpDaemon, то действительно, из-за скудной документации и, подчас неактуальной, трудности есть. Но за последние полгода ситуация изменилась, разработчик многое актуализировал. К примеру, его нынешний [**чат**][1], использует актуальную версию PhpDaemon-а.

  [1]: https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon-muchat